# calling a user defined function from component(cfc) doesnt work

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I am calling the function (JoblistAdd) inside the   tag.

See the below code in Index.cfm

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="TimesheetHours" jsclassname="js_TimesheetHours"> 

<script >
 var obj_TimesheetHours = new js_TimesheetHours();
var strMsglist=
obj_TimesheetHours.JoblistAdd(selectedJobArray,userID,weekending,tsApproved);
</script>
```

Below , component code TimesheetHours.CFC

```
<cffunction name="JoblistAdd" >
<cfargument name="AddList" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="userID" required="yes"  >
<cfargument name="weekending"  required="yes" >
<cfargument name="Approved"  required="false" >

<cfset JobArray =arguments.AddList>
<cfset userID =arguments.userID>
<cfset weekending =arguments.weekending>
<cfset tsApproved =arguments.Approved>
    <cfdump var="#JobArray #"><cfabort>
</cffunction>
```

But i could not able to reach till the dump ,
I think it is not coming inside the function , Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arasu,

You have to give the access attribute as 'remote'. In your case its by defualt public.

```
<cffunction name="JoblistAdd" access="remote">
```

hope that helps.